# SqlDataSource and "Contains" when a comma or space is part of search string

Tags: c#, asp.net, escaping, contains, sqldatasource

I am writing an application in Asp.net with c# as code behind.  I have a text box ("txtNameSearch") for the user place information into to filter a SqlDataSource, and a gridview that populates based that SQL data.  When the users places a comma or space in the box, the SqLDataSource has an exception error.  I want to be able to allow this sort of search because the database has punctuation allowed in this field.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Sql_NameList" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Recorder %>'
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [Address1], [Address2], [CSZ], [PersonID] FROM [People] WHERE (CONTAINS([Name], @Name))">

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtNameSearch" PropertyName="Text" Name="Name" Type="String">
            </asp:ControlParameter>
        </SelectParameters>

    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Below is the exception text:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Syntax error near ',' in the full-text search condition 'Johnson, Ma'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Syntax error
>   near ',' in the full-text search condition 'Johnson, Ma'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Syntax error near ',' in the full-text
>   search condition 'Johnson, Ma'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +2442126
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5736904    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +628
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +3731
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +58
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +89
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +379
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +2026
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +375
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +53
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +240
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +41
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +12    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +139
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +136
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable) +86
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +1494
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +22
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   +75    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +883

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem in the c# code behind by taking the text box and checking for a comma or space.  If that exists quotation marks are added around the text and then the query does not choke on the comma or space.  See code below:

```
        if (txtNameSearch.Text.Contains(",") || txtNameSearch.Text.Contains(" "))
            {
            if (txtNameSearch.Text.Contains('"'))
                {

                }
            else
                {
                txtNameSearch.Text = '"' + txtNameSearch.Text + '"';
                }
            }
```